# Como parsear un xml que devuelve response.content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola a todos al hacer una consulta a una API me devuelve como resultado un xml, donde de dicho xml me interesa un codigo que me envia, pero no puedo obtenerlo

alguien puede darme alguna idea

```
<RESPONSE><FIELDS><FIELD KEY=\"TAC">w5cx1M47OkzbztZbEbHzYpLyx5BQsTjKFMbU2EHA3Qt0S5A+1v6PCuq5wojO94pNBBHKOc97lbI=</FIELD></FIELDS></RESPONSE>\n
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Intenta probar con [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8401375/5622844) respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias NaCI me ayudo esa respuesta

Comment: Considera editar la pregunta para que agregues el código que buscar tu xml, luego respondete :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias deserializar el xml a una clase, primero accedes a

https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

generando las clases

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="FIELD")]
    public class FIELD {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="KEY")]
        public string KEY { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="FIELDS")]
    public class FIELDS {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FIELD")]
        public FIELD FIELD { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="RESPONSE")]
    public class RESPONSE {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FIELDS")]
        public FIELDS FIELDS { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Para despues deserializar usando

[Simple deserialization of XML to C# object](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11)

```
string xml = @"<RESPONSE>
                  <FIELDS>
                   <FIELD KEY="TAC">w5cx1M47OkzbztZbEbHzYpLyx5BQsTjKFMbU2EHA3Qt0S5A+1v6PCuq5wojO94pNBBHKOc97lbI=                 
                   </FIELD>
                  </FIELDS>
                </RESPONSE>";

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
RESPONSE response= (RESPONSE)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

veras se usa la clase `RESPONSE` para deserializar el xml

Comment: Excelente Leandro gracias